# Reconstruction of media library db - what am I missing?

Tags: wordpress

One of my devs used a media cleaner plug-in that did a lot of damage i.e. clean files which were in fact still needed. Now I am trying to reconstruct the media library to a state before the media cleaner plug-in was used.

The actual files could easily be recovered from a backup of the site before we did our changes, but the database needs a little more care as we deleted and changed quite a few posts that were obsolete and I do not want to lose that work by replacing the complete DB with the original data.

Now I have manually been copying a few database entries from the backup db into my wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables, as well as the table that contains the file names for the EWWWOptimizer that converts the images into various resolutions for speed optimization.

I've checked all the filenames and they are physically present on the server and yet I cannot convince the pictures to reappear on my website again, although I manage to get some thumbnails to appear in the backend.

Especially my picture gallery plugin ("RoyalSlider") does not seems to register the reconstructed data.

Am I missing a database table or any other spot where I should reconstruct data?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, images were there after reconstruction but size 1x1 px. No idea where to fix that in the DB, so just hacked it with CSS.